# Javascript on page load: works in console, but not on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to run this javascript on my homepage when it loads:

```
  $(".mm-page").css({"position":"inherit"});
```

I added this at the bottom of my home.html.erb:

```
<% content_for(:after_js) do %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    console.log("before");
    $(".mm-page").css({"position":"inherit"});
    console.log("after");
  </script>
<% end %>
```

Both console.log appear in the console, but the jquery has no effect. If I manually run the jquery line in the console, it works as expected.

How should I proceed to fix this ?

Comment: Add the script in dom ready handler and try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to make it work on page when it load you should wrap it inside ready handler.The `ready()` method specifies what happens when a ready event occurs.

Two syntaxes can be used:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".mm-page").css({"position":"inherit"});
});
```

**OR**

```
$(function() {
    $(".mm-page").css({"position":"inherit"});
});
```

Also be sure that the element `.mm-page` exists in the moment you're using it with the jQuery selector.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that all of the DOM elements it operates on exist, put the `script` tag at the very bottom of the HTML, just prior to the closing `</body>` tag. All of the elements defined by the HTML above it will then be available for use. This also ensures that the browser can show the user the page prior to downloading any external script files you reference. E.g.:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<!-- ...your page here... -->
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  console.log("before");
  $(".mm-page").css({"position":"inherit"});
  console.log("after");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You'll need to translate that to whatever rendering engine you're using, but you get the idea. The end result going to the browser should look like that.

Alternately, you *can* use jQuery's `ready` callback, but with the script tags in the correct location, it's unnecessary.

---

Side note: The default `type` is JavaScript, there's no need to specify it on the `script` tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log appear in the console
```

Because your `DOM` has finished loading and it is now ready to use.

That's why you are getting jQuery effect.

In your current script,it is not waiting to finish `DOM` loading and directly operating on it which is not available as it is not finished loading.

Eiher write script it in

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

OR :

```
$(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```